# Use LINQ on Dictionary(of Int, Custom Structure)

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a collection of records in a dictonary collection.
In VB can how do I use LINQ to query Dictionary(Of Integer, DeckClass)?

```
Public Class DeckClass
  Public Deck_Key As Integer
  Public Deck_Item1 As String
  Public Deck_Item2 As String
  Public Deck_Item2 As Double
End Class
```

I am using Visual Studio 2012 Express.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Also, what kind of query? This is a non question - you are asking how to use a query language to query, but don't supply what you want to query for.

Comment: “What have you tried? “ I researched several forums and was unable to find or apply the techniques nor was I sure I was even on the right path. “Also, what kind of query?” Hmm, a LINQ query… ??  “This is a non question - you are asking how to use a query language to query, but don't supply what you want to query for.”  Well Reed seam to understand the question and provided exactly what I needed.

Comment: Closed as not a real question?? The question was already answered. So I guess the answer is not a real answer as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Dictionary.Values`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x.aspx) to search through your `DeckClass` instances.  [`Dictionary(Of Int,DeckClass)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) also implements `IEnumerable(Of KeyValuePair(Of Int, DeckClass))`, so you can search through the `KeyValuePair` instances directly, as well.

For example, if you wanted a list of keys which stored a `DeckClass` where `Deck_Item1` was equal to `"Foo"`, you could use:

```
Dim keys = dict.Where(Function(kvp) kvp.Value.Deck_Item1 = "Foo").Select(Function(kvp) kvp.Key))
```

Comment: Reed, thanks the dots connected. Can you recommend a book that discusses LINQ and Collections clearly and in detail?

Comment: @user2012251 LINQ in Action is supposedly good: http://www.amazon.com/dp/1933988169/?tag=stackoverfl08-20

Comment: I just wanted to say thanks again. I am not sure why but the simple example you provided opened the floodgates of understanding and I am just cooking along now with collections and LINQ.